# Pgbouncer on large client connections

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I need to configure my pgbouncer for work with more than 2000 clients connections, I was reading some information about how to work with max connections, then I have understood what I must to do **max_client_con = 2000** on pgbouncer, but what about **default_pool_size**, them, more than a question is to ask for some support in order to understand the right way on configure pgbouncer on large client connections

**postgres.conf**

```
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directory = '/var/run/postgresql'           # (change requires restart)
```

**pgbouncer.ini**

```
[pgbouncer]
logfile = /var/log/postgresql/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /var/run/postgresql/pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr = 127.0.0.1
listen_port = 6432
unix_socket_dir = /var/run/postgresql
auth_type = md5
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
admin_users = carlos
pool_mode = statement
server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL
max_client_conn = 100
default_pool_size = 20
```

Comment: What are those 2,000 clients? Are they trying to hit the databases directly or they connect to a web application or some other service that queries the db server with its own user? That makes all the difference.

Comment: They are are connection from a gps listener, this listener receives data on 10 seconds intervals from gps trackers, and then the data is stored on the postgres database

Comment: If the listener is the only one connecting to pgbouncer then you have one only client which can make _n_ simultaneous connections. How many depends on the duration of each connection. Is the listener a PC? Is it on the same machine as the DB? Where is pgbouncer listening? On the listener or on the DB server?

Comment: Hmmm the listener is a twisted app, wich one manage multiple protocols and it creates a connection for each gps tracker device, I have found the solution on it, however thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can run pgbouncer in "transaction pooling mode", you're best off. There are a few features that if use will not work with that, but if you don't use them for that.

default_pool_size then controls how many connections you have between pgbouncer and postgresql, and leaving that at something like 20 is probably a good idea. That means you can have 20 *simultaneously active transactions* in the system, and from the description of what you're doing that seems unlikely. But you want to adjust that value to be a value with a "reasonable margin" over the maximum number of simultaneous transactions you need. pgbouncer will then happily multiplex your 2000 connections over these 20, maintaining good performance on the database side.